# streaming video from vitec ip camera using direct link

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

i'm using vitec ip camera (model: ip 623 mir) and i want to stream the output video from web page (html5) or c++ script (opencv), the problem is that i can't find the correct link (url) to get direct acces to the video from the camera, i have tried to use those links,

"http://user:pwd@ipadress:port/videostream.asf"

"http://user:pwd@ipadress:port/video.cgi"

but the path to the video is incorrect, i undrestand that each camera hase his own path to the video and i can't find the true path to my camera.

also there is three 3 ports specified on the control page of the camera :

```
 8200: media port 
 80  : web port
 554 : rtsp port
```

i don't know who is the port used to stream the output video.

Comment: You'll have to try and find the information in the camera's documentation. There is no way for us to guess the correct URL.

Comment: i have found the right url without the camera documentation (the camera documentation is very poor, just one page), the working url is : rstp://ipadress:554/